# Ordenação absoluta pelos dados retornados da DB

Tags: php, mysql, classificação

Em PHP estou a fazer uma consulta a minha base de dados usando o MySQL. Na minha base de dados tenho a tabela `fotos_album` e lá dentro tenho o nome da foto. Eu quero ordenar a tabela pelo campo `nome`.

Imaginamos que a tabela tem os seguintes dados:

```
id         nome
1          corrida (1 de 140)
2          corrida (20 de 140)
3          corrida (5 de 140)
4          corrida (2 de 140)
```

O objectivo é que a minha ordenação fique do seguinte modo:

```
id         nome
1          corrida (1 de 140)
4          corrida (2 de 140)
3          corrida (5 de 140)
2          corrida (20 de 140)
```

Para tal acontecer não basta usar `ORDER BY nome ASC`, então como posso fazer com que a ordenação seja correcta?

Editado: O nome é inserido pelo utilizador. Se ele inserir o campo nome como escrevi em cima, uma simples ordenação não resulta

Eu tentei o seguinte, mas não funciona correctamente em todos os casos:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM fotos_album
WHERE id = '$id_noticia'
ORDER BY 
  SUBSTR(nome,
     LEAST(
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('0', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('0', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('1', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('1', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('2', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('2', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('3', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('3', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('4', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('4', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('5', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('5', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('6', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('6', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('7', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('7', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('8', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('8', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END,
       CASE WHEN LOCATE('9', nome)>0 THEN LOCATE('9', nome) ELSE LENGTH(nome) END
     )
   ) + 0
```

Comment: Acho que para realizar tal ordenação tu deveria repensar em como está a tua tabela no MySQL, pois a mesma não esta normalizada, sendo assim o teu desenvolvimento vai ser muito mais complexo. Para ter uma base, da uma olhada aqui: http://www.luis.blog.br/normalizacao-de-dados-e-as-formas-normais.aspx

Comment: Não, o utilizador é que mete aquele nome. Ele podia meter outro qualquer. O utilizador quer que seja sempre ordenado como estou a pedir, mas se ele inserir o campo nome como meti em cima, a simples ordenação não resulta

Comment: O que pode ter no campo `nome`? Somente `corrida (M de N)` ou qualquer coisa? Por exemplo, o nome pode ser `aa`, `b`, `15` ou `140`? Vi que você já aceitou uma resposta, mas não creio que ela funcione no caso geral - só para esse exemplo específico. (em outra palavras, se você está buscando uma ordenação "à lá windows explorer" - onde os números aparecem em ordem crescente e as letras em ordem lexicográfica - a solução certamente será mais complexa do que se espera, se é que há mesmo uma solução possível...)

Comment: sim, pode ter qualquer coisa. Mas aconselha outra resolução?

Comment: Ok, vamos pensar então... tu consegue garantir que o cliente sempre irá inserir seguindo esse template: `corrida (x de y)` ? Tem como tu usar uma máscara para isso na input do cliente? se tu conseguir garantir isso, podemos pensar em uma forma de resolver usando apenas o SQL, por mais que seja complexo, é possível.

Comment: não, eu não consigo garantir que ele insira sempre no formato corrida (x de y)

Comment: Sei que ainda não esta funcionando, mas serve para o pessoal ir fazendo os teste. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09281/2

Comment: Segue uma continuação do exemplo e se for possível, peça para seu cliente entrar com os dados da forma desse exemplo que com isso irá funcionar o que precisa. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/477a8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experimente utilizar o seguinte código:

```
SELECT nome FROM fotos_album ORDER BY LENGTH(nome), nome
```

Comment: E se ele decidir adicionar o dado `5          corrida (05 de 140)` ?

Comment: nesse caso irá ordenar da maneira que procuro.

Comment: Embora essa resposta funcione nesse caso bem específico, vai falhar em muitos outros. Ex.: `corrida(1 de 1)` vs. `aaaaaaaaa(1 de 1)`. Ou `corrida(10 de 10)` vs. `corrida(1 de 10000)`. Essa resposta estará correta somente se o valor estiver no formato `A(B de C)` sendo que `A` e `C` estão fixos (e se esse for o caso, o que o OP *realmente* precisa é normalizar seu BD).

Answer (score 4):

Assumindo que `nome` é um campo textual aberto, o que parece estar incomodando seu cliente é que a ordenação lexicográfica não leva em consideração a interpretação que um humano daria para a string. Enquanto o computador vê somente uma sequência de caracteres (no máximo, levando em conta o *collation* do seu idioma), um humano vê uma série de palavras, sinais, números, que para ele segue uma estrutura lógica:

```
"corrida(20 de 140)" ::== Nome de uma coleção, "(", índice, " de ", total, ")"
```

E ele espera que o computador seja capaz de reconhecer essa estrutura e dar aos seus elementos uma ordem natural (i.e. se o nome da coleção e o total forem fixos, os índices têm de estar em ordem crescente). Acontece que o computador não vê as coisas dessa maneira. Para ele a string `corrida(20 de 140)` não é diferente de `corrida(9001 de -42)` que não é diferente de `alllll234hlkhssdf`.

Uma pessoa com um mínimo de entendimento disso simplesmente daria de ombros e renomearia suas fotos para:

```
corrida(001 de 140)
corrida(020 de 140)
corrida(005 de 140)
corrida(002 de 140)
```

Mas se o cliente insiste nisso, e você quer agradar a ele custe o que custar, eu sugeriria o seguinte:

1. Quebre sua string em pedaços, onde cada pedaço é um número (`\d+`) ou não (`\D+`);
2. Interprete os números como números (i.e. não como texto), e ordene-os como tal;
3. O que não é número, ordene de forma lexicográfica, respeitando o *collation* do seu idioma.

(Esclarecendo: represente seu nome como uma lista `["corrida(", 1, " de ", 140, ")"]` e ordene pelo primeiro elemento, depois pelo segundo, e assim por diante)

Provavelmente isso será complexo demais para fazer somente via SQL, sendo melhor realizado na sua camada de aplicação ou talvez como um *stored procedure*.

**Atualização:** Eu não tenho como sugerir nada além do que foi proposto acima, sua nova tentativa de solução falha porque ignora o começo da string (ex.: `b1` apareceria antes de `a2`) e também porque *ainda* compara como string - não como número (a menos que aquele `+ 0` no final, que não entendi o que faz, esteja de fato fazendo um *cast* implícito para número).

Entretanto, posso sugerir uma massa de dados para teste - pois é importante lembrar que nem todo arquivo na sua base vai ter o mesmo formato, ou mesmo pertencer ao mesmo usuário; uma tabela guarda dados de todo tipo, não só de uma coleção específica. Seja qual for a solução adotada, certifique-se que ela funciona nos seguintes casos:

```
arvore
árvore
arvore(40 de 50)
cor(60 de 140)
corrida 20/5
corrida 20/20
corrida 140/5
corrida 140/20
corrida(5 de 20)
corrida(5 de 140)
corrida(20 de 20)
corrida(20 de 140)
palavramuitogrande(1 de 1)
```

Visto que:

- Se seu *collation* estiver errado, `árvore` vai estar depois de `palavramuitogrande`;
- Se você ordenar por length primeiro e depois por conteúdo, `cor(60 de 140)` vai estar antes de `arvore(40 de 50)`;
- Se você ordenar pelo primeiro número encontrado, `palavramuitogrande` vai estar antes de `cor` (se se seu *fallback* for o length, também estará antes de `arvore`).
- Se você usar minha sugestão acima, a ordem ficará como na lista proposta. Mas note que o cliente **ainda pode reclamar** que `corrida(5 de 140)` está entre `corrida(5 de 20)` e `corrida(20 de 20)`...

  - E a tentativa de resolver esse caso vai trazer mais complicações (ex.: `corrida N/M` vai ficar com a ordem errada). Não dá pra fazer mágica, o cliente tem que entender que o computador não tem inteligência para ordenar sempre como ele quer.

Etc. Preste atenção nisso, pois não adianta nada você se focar demais nesse requisito específico agora, se depois sua ordenação se mostrar completamente doida, quando seu sistema estiver em prática num caso real.

Comment: eu editei a minha questão, eu tentei o último código, mas nem sempre funciona correctamente e não consigo perceber porque

Comment: @pc_oc Eu atualizei minha resposta com um comentário sobre seu último método, mas infelizmente não tenho alternativas a sugerir. Como minha resposta original dizia, não dá pro computador "pensar" que nem um ser humano, de um jeito ou de outro você vai enfrentar problemas se tentar agradar ao cliente a qualquer custo. Eu sugeri uma listinha de palavras que talvez te ajude a esclarecer, na sua cabeça, qual é seu requisito real.